# Изменить цвет подсказки

Tags: html, css

Как изменить цвет подсказки `placeholder` для `input search`?

```
<form method="get" action="/search/name">
    <input type="search" name="query" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Кого будем искать?">
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#fff;}
::-moz-placeholder          {color:#fff;}
:-moz-placeholder           {color:#fff;}
:-ms-input-placeholder      {color:#fff;}
```

А точнее

```css
.myclass::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: red; }
.myclass::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: red); }
.myclass:-moz-placeholder {
        color: red; }
.myclass:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: red; }
```

```html
<input class="myclass" type="search" name="query" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Кого будем искать?">
```